# How do you save the function from a function pointer as a class' member function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Basically, I have a templated class that runs some algorithm, and that algorithm needs a `similarity(T t1, T t2)` function that returns a double defining how similar two objects of type T are.  This similarity function varies greatly depending on what T is defined as, so the caller of this class needs to define the similarity function.  I assume a function pointer is in order, but how do I save a function from a function pointer as a member function for use in the algorithm?

That is, I want to pass in `similarity(T t1, T t2)` in the class' constructor and be able to call that as a member function throughout the class.  How do I do that?  Thanks

Comment: Besides function pointer a `virtual` interface and/or `std::function`/`boost::function` may be in order.

Comment: Here's one that doesn't use `std::function`: http://ideone.com/2A4Rc. If you have access to `std::function`, it's a whole lot more flexible, though. Using that, you can use `std::bind` to bind an object to it if you want to use that object's members.

Comment: Any reason you cannot make specializations of `similarity` visible to the code using your algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add member functions to a class at runtime.

You could write a member function that calls the supplied function via the function pointer:

```
class MyClass {
    typedef double (*similarity_fn_type)(T t1, T t2);
    similarity_fn_type similarity_fn;
  public:
    MyClass(similarity_fn_type ptr) : similarity_fn(ptr) {}
    double similarity(T t1, T t2) {
        return similarity_fn(t1, t2);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you *could* make the `similarity_fn` member public. The syntax for calling it would make it look like a member function, but you might not consider it to be great encapsulation.

Comment: I would *not* make the function public, having it public means that external code can change it to any other function or perform any other nasty modification...

Comment: @David: that's one consequence of "not great encapsulation" (assuming the member is non-const, which it is here to allow for assignment of `MyClass`). Sometimes a design calls for great encapsulation to be enforced by the language, other times it doesn't. Examples where it doesn't include (a) all Python programs, (b) all C structs, (c) POD structs in C++, so there's plenty of precedent.

Comment: I understand from the question that he wants to call it as a member function only from other members of the class, where the access is not needed. As of the other examples, python ... well, what can I say... C libraries in many cases offer a level of encapsulation greater than usual C++ approaches by means of opaque pointers and yes, POD types are specifically designed not to encapsulate :) At any rate, the comment was because I believe that he does not want to call the function from outside the class, but only internally.

Comment: @David: Ah, gotcha. Yes, in that case my `similarity` member function is pointless. All that's needed is the private function pointer, and the syntax for calling it makes it look like a member function of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

There are cleaner, object-oriented ways to do that. One of them is to pass an object with that function, similar to how Java allows reimplementing comparisons with the Comparator class. This implies the creation of a base class (with that function as purely virtual) and a subclass for each implementation of `similarity()`.

In your case, you may find more useful the solution C++11 takes for implementing functions for comparing and hashing. It involves creating special function objects. See [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) and [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for examples.

Comment: I won’t downvote, but I do disagree. In idiomatic C++, generic programming (static polymorphism) is preferred to object-oriented programming (runtime polymorphism) where possible.

Comment: I understand the concern here. My experience in Java made me less worried about runtime polymorphism, which can be avoided in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it’s mainly a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to abstract away the process of iterating through a collection. I use a predicate to specify the actual search criteria:

```
void MyClass::Copy(Class &destination, const Class &source, const std::function<bool (const Effect&)> &predicate)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Effect::Max; ++i)
    {
        const Effect *const pEffect = source.GetEffect(i);
        if (predicate(*pEffect))
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

void MyClass::CopyInner(Class &destination, const Class &source)
{
    this->Copy(destination, source, [](const Effect &effect)
    {
        return effect.IsInner();
    });
}
```

**Note**: This uses some C++11 features.

Comment: This could also be the traditional `template<class Pred>` rather than take a `std::function`. That way it requires no dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Jon: it can be a class template provided that you want the type of the `MyClass` object to depend on the type of the "predicate".

Comment: @SteveJessop: That’s another option, and perhaps more semantically correct, but it’s not very pleasant in C++. You have no common interface without either making a base class or making all `MyClass` consumers into templates.

Comment: @Jon: maybe I've misunderstood. I thought you were suggesting `template<class Pred>`, so I pointed out the consequence. Now you say it's "another option", so I'm puzzled what the option is that you were suggesting. Personally I find programming with templates to be reasonably pleasant, I just wouldn't send a beginner down that route without preparation :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh, I was suggesting making the *member function* a template, not the whole class. Templates are fine, and I’m a big fan of generic programming, but the C++ template syntax can obscure some of their utility. Compare `template<class T> T f(T, T);` to `f :: t -> t -> t`.

Comment: Using templates for the predicate seems like an unnecessary complication, unless speed is absolutely crucial and you've got a well-defined API.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `const` function pointer member of the appropriate type:

```
typedef double(*Similarity)(T, T);
const Similarity similarity;
```

Let the constructor accept a function of that type:

```
Class(Similarity f) : similarity(f) {}
```

Then calling the function has the same syntax as calling an ordinary member function:

```
frobnicate(similarity(foo, bar));
```

And if the member is `public`, it cannot be changed out from under you because it’s `const`.